# Modular Arithmetic Proof, Primes and Squares

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

We write x ≡ y (mod m) for integers x, y, and m > 0 if m | (x − y).
Prove: for all integers z, either $z^2$ ≡ 0 (mod 4) or $z^2$ ≡ 1 (mod 4). 
Hint: Distinguish two cases according to the parity of z.

Some prime numbers can be represented as the sum of two squares; e.g., $5 = 2^2 + 1^2$, $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$. Others, such as 3, 7, 11, cannot.

State a rule as to which primes can and which primes cannot be represented as the sum of two squares.

Give a proof to show that the primes you conjecture cannot be represented as the sum of two squares, in fact, cannot. The first part of this problem can be used.

Comment: do you know what $x\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ means ? lets try that first.

Comment: the OP really copied $5 =2^2+1^2$ to $5 = 22+12$. You are supposed to work on your exercice before asking it on internet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part use the fact that the complete residue system of $4$ is $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Hence you just need to compute the square values of each to get all possible quadratic residues and this can be easily done by hand.

For the second part, use the first part to see that a sum of squares has to be congruent to $0,1,2$ modulo $4$. So this enables to conclude that primes of the form $p=4k+3$ can not be represented as a sum of two squares. Also except 2, there isn't a prime of the form $4k+2$, as well as $4k$.

You can prove that each prime of the form $p=4k+1$ can be represented as a sum of two squares, but the proof isn't simple enough as it uses Gaussian Integers.

Comment: Gaussian integers and quadratic reciprocity. The proofs are listed [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)